# Manipulating GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I want my `GridView` to display only 16 random letters, a 4x4 tile and if it's possible I don't want any space between the letters.
I also want it to display its corresponding text to a `TextView` to form a word. I put it in a toast for now to show how it should be. But it only shows the corresponding letter of the image. How can I achieve that? I dont have any idea on how should i do it.
Any help will be appreciated.

***New to Android Programming***

[image]
[image]

**grid_row.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >
 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
        </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```js
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.grid.gridgame.MainActivity" >
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wordHere"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1234567890"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewCustom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```js
package com.grid.gridgame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 GridView gridView;
 String word;
 int rando;
 static final String[] setOne = new String[] { 
  "A", "M","C", "Qu",
  "Z", "B", "D", "A",
  "E", "I", "E", "L",
  "M", "N", "T", "P" };
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewCustom);
        
        gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewCustomAdapter(this, setOne));
        
  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
     int position, long id) {
    
    Toast.makeText(
       getApplicationContext(),
       ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView))
       .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 
   }
  });
        
        
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**GridViewCustomAdapter**

```js
package com.grid.gridgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class GridViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private Context context;
 private final String[] setOne;
 
 public GridViewCustomAdapter(Context context, String[] setOne) {
  this.context = context;
  this.setOne = setOne;
 }
 
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 
  View gridView;
 
  if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = new ImageView(context);
   gridView = new View(context);
 
   // get layout from mobile.xml
   gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row, null);
 
   // set value into TextView
   TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
     .findViewById(R.id.textView);
   
   textView.setText(setOne[position]);
 
   // set image based on selected text
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
     .findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
 
   String allletters = setOne[position];
   
   if (allletters.equals("A")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
   } else if (allletters.equals("M")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.m);
   } else if (allletters.equals("C")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
   } else if (allletters.equals("Qu")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.qu);
    
   } else if (allletters.equals("Z")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.z);
   } else if (allletters.equals("B")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
   } else if (allletters.equals("D")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
   } else if (allletters.equals("A")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
    
   } else if (allletters.equals("E")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.e);
   } else if (allletters.equals("I")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.i);
   } else if (allletters.equals("E")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.e);
   } else if (allletters.equals("M")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.m);
    

   } else if (allletters.equals("M")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.m);
   } else if (allletters.equals("N")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.n);
   } else if (allletters.equals("T")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.t);
   } else if (allletters.equals("P")) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.p);
   }

  } else {
   gridView = (View) convertView;
   
  }
 
  return gridView;
 }
 
 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return setOne.length;
 }
 
 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }
 
 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

}
```

Comment: Please post complete activity_main.xml. There will be some layout definition in it. Complete file please. That file determines the visibility of that TextView.

Comment: Please add an `android:text="12345678"` to that TextView to see if it becomes visible. And remove that visibility!

Comment: Just put only first 16 letters in MOBILE_OS. Otherwise your GridView becomes to big.

Comment: @greenapps I already edited the questios above using my current codes

Comment: @LabLey Sorry here n/w problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65141/discussion-on-question-by-lab-ley-manipulating-gridview).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the letter you can simply create a string and store the letter push by user.

```
Example code:
String word;    // word that you want to be display

String letter = MOBILE_OS[id];     // get the corresponding letter from array from the user selected 

word.add(letter);
```

Comment: Put it in gridView.setOnItemClickListener. Once the user pressed a key on the screen you can get the corresponding letter and then store it in the word string

Comment: it shiws an error in word.add(letter); --> the method add(string[]) is under definfed for the type of string @user3806339

Comment: Sorry I forgot there is no add method for string. To add character to string just use string += char;

Comment: can you help me how should i do that? @user3806339